# NextJs Index.html file not generated in Public Folder

Tags: reactjs, build, next.js, npm-build

So i have a NextJS project going on. And everytime I try to run NPM RUN BUILD i don't get an index.html file in my public folder, and that causes google firebase deploy not work properly.

It used to work before but not anymore, why is that?[image]

Comment: Do you have an `index.js` in your `pages` folder? The `'public` folder is for static file serving, it's not where the index is being sent. 

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

Comment: yes i do have an index,js file in the pages folder.

Comment: When you build a next project, the files that are generated go into `.next`, not `public`.  https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

Comment: ok, so what im trying to do is host my nextjs project on firebase. now when I run firebase deploy for hosting, firebase keeps creating an index.html and 404.html files in the public directory and serves that only. how can I make it serve the actual site?

Comment: I have the same issue, any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to your `package.json` and modify the build script into `"next build && next export"`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build && next export",
  },
```

Now run the `npm run build` command, that will generate an `out` folder containing your static website (use it's content same as if it was called `public`).

[Example of the package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp9IE.png)

[Example of the `out` folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBFib.png)